# Splash screen not showing on android

Tags: flutter, native, splash-screen

I am using native_splash_screen and its not showing on android, on iOS is working fine, but I cant make it to work on android.

```
flutter_native_splash:
```

background_image: "packages/components/assets/splash1x.png"
android_12:
image: "packages/components/assets/splash1x.png"
android: true
ios: true

Comment: Which version of Android?

Comment: The version of Android is 12

Answer (score 1):

**Android 12+ Support**

Android 12 has a [new method](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) of adding splash screens, which consists of a window background, icon, and the icon background. Note that a background image is not supported.

[image]

1. image parameter. By default, the launcher icon is used:

- App icon without an icon background, as shown on the left: This
  should be 1152×1152 pixels, and fit within a circle 768 pixels in
  diameter.
- App icon with an icon background, as shown on the right: This should be
  960×960 pixels, and fit within a circle 640 pixels in diameter.

2. icon_background_color is optional, and is useful if you need more contrast between the icon and the window background
3. One-third of the foreground is masked.
4. color the window background consists of a single opaque color.

For example

```
flutter_native_splash:
  ...
  android_12:
    image: assets/logo.png
    icon_background_color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: assets/logo.png
    icon_background_color_dark: "#121212"
```

Comment: The problem is that id doesnt not appear on the screen, the screen is still white on android, on ios it is working fine.

Comment: flutter_native_splash: 
  background_image: "packages/components/assets/splash1x.png"   
  android_12:
    image: "packages/components/assets/splash1x.png" 
    icon_background_color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: "packages/components/assets/splash1x.png"
    icon_background_color_dark: "#ffffff"
  android: true 
  ios: true